# Some difficulties in Python on Begginer level

Tags: python

Sorry if I'm asking something dumb. I'm begginer btw.
Can I somehow place multiple variables in one variable, like:

```
login = "user"
enter = input(login + ">")
commandLogin = "login"
commandRegister = "register"
commandExit = "exit"
commandList = commandLogin, commandRegister, commandExit

while enter != commandList:
    print("incorrect command!")
    enter = input(login + ">")
```

Comment: If you can post the code in this post it would be better.

Comment: Python offers many ways to do this sort of thing. You can use a tuple:  a = (7, -2, "Hi"), a list: a = [13, "Hello", 2], a dictionary a = {1:12, 62:"Hi", 12:7}, or you can create a CLASS. As a beginner you should start off by studying tuples and lists.

Comment: @user10637953 Please don't post answers in the comments. Post it as an answer instead.

Comment: What I offered wasn't an answer so much as suggestions for self-study. A comment seemed the best way to go.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the code as text, [not an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). While you're there, please use a descriptive title, like for example, "Can I put multiple variables in one variable?" BTW welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question here. If you want to check if `enter` is not a valid command, use `enter not in commandList`. See [How to test that variable is not equal to multiple things?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12553609/4518341)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an 'iterable', such as a `tuple` or a `list`. Check here: [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=iterable#sequence-types-list-tuple-range)
So for your code you can use:

```
login = "user"
commandLogin = "login"
commandRegister = "register"
commandExit = "exit"
commandList = [commandLogin, commandRegister, commandExit]

enter = input(login + ">")
while enter not in commandList:
    print("Incorrect command!")
    enter = input(login + ">")
```

Comment: You don't even need the square brackets: `commandList = commandLogin, commandRegister, commandExit` is fine. The key change is the `not in` check.

Comment: Yes. If there are no brackets it would be a `tuple`, which also works in this code. @sabik

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the example you're already doing that.

The main correction is that you probably want `while enter not in commandList`

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can use a dictionary to put multiple variables in one variable:

```
>>> a={}
>>> a['first']='this is the first'
>>> a['second']='the second'
>>> a
{'first': 'this is the first', 'second': 'the second'}
>>> a['first']
'this is the first'
>>>
```

You can also create a class, an object of the class, and access attributes:

```
>>> class Empty():
...     pass
...
>>> a = Empty()
>>> a.first = 'the first value'
>>> a.second = 'the second value'
>>> a
<__main__.Empty object at 0x7fceb005dbd0>
>>> a.first
'the first value'
>>> a.second
'the second value'
>>> a.third
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Empty' object has no attribute 'third'
>>>
```

In your example, you probably want to use a list:

```
>>> a = []
>>> a.append("first")
>>> a.append("second")
>>> a.append("third")
>>> a
['first', 'second', 'third']
>>>
```

But it's not really clear what you are trying to do in your example.

Answer (score 0):

The result of this is a `tuple`. A `tuple` is similar to a list but once a tuple is created, the values cannot be changed. The technique in the code is called **tuple packing** and essentially just creates a `tuple`.

Answer (score 0):

When you separate multiple variables by comma without any surrounding parenthesis, python creates a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) for you:

```py
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

# implicit tuple
x = a, b, c

# equivalent, explicit tuple
x = (a, b, c)
```

Likewise, you can expand a tuple (or any iterable) into multiple variables:

```py
# Expanding a tuple
x = (1, 2, 3)
a, b, c = x  # a=1, b=2, c=3

# Expanding a list
x = [1, 2, 3]
a, b, c = x  # a=1, b=2, c=3

# Expanding a dict (the keys are expanded into the new variables)
x = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
a, b = x  # a = 'a', b = 'b'

# Expanding an iterator
a, b = range(2)  # a=0, b=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
login = "user"
enter = input(login + ">")
commandLogin = "login"
commandRegister = "register"
commandExit = "exit"
commandList = commandLogin, commandRegister, commandExit

while enter != commandList:
    print("incorrect command!")
    enter = input(login + ">")
```

This should do it

Answer (score -1):

Yes You can Place multiple Variable
but avoid it
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/assigning-multiple-variables-in-one-line-in-python/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).